# How to hide a row of a table which does not contains a specific icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with some items and those items can be selected by adding a tick. Check the image attached:

[image: The table contains the items and some of them has various ticks]

What I need to achieve is to hide the row which does not contain any ticks to be not visible. This is because in my app I have to generate lists of the items contains only ticks in another view. So when I will press the generate button that row will be hidden. 
I just want to say if that row does not contain any 'glyphicon-ok' need to be deleted/hidden when I will generate the view with the list of those items.

I tried something like this:

```
SveCrf.prototype.hideRowWhereNoTicksForm = function () {
    var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        switch (tr.item(i).getElementsByTagName('td').item(0).className) {
            case "glyphicon-ok":
                tr.item(i).style.display = "none";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't do anything.
I would like to see an example of being able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you getting those data with a sql query? Cause if you only want to select with ticks in it just specify that in your where statement

Comment: I think filtering the data should happen at some point before, either on the database query as @Tomm suggested or after getting the data and before initially filling the table.
Anyways to find out why nothing is happening with your code we need to see the html markup of your table, so it'd be great if you could provide that too.

Comment: Yes, those data came from an SQL. So I cannot do that by javascript to hide that row? An example of what you mean will be glad to see for better understanding @Tomm

Comment: @Jakub i would love to provide an example if you give me code to work with ;)

Comment: @Tomm The code I'm working on is a Rails application and I'm sharing pastes of the codes doing this table:
https://pastebin.com/ibJYiiCB
https://pastebin.com/ZMgg2ZFt
https://pastebin.com/i7cP4pzm

Those 3 are model controller and the Js regarding the table generation

Comment: @Jakub where is the query your using now ?\

Comment: @Tomm in the code is where is the SoA table called also Schedule fo Assessments Table

Comment: @Jakub I am not any familiar with rails, I am familiar with sql coding, thats why i need a raw query

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I'm sorry but is not my same issue. I want to hide a row based if has or has not the Glypican icon in the cells

Comment: So the examples I checked until now hey really do not help me with my specific situation.

Comment: Break your issue into parts.  Find the row first.  This has been done millions of times before by thousands upon thousands of developers, so you can do it too.  Once you find the row, hide it, again, something that has been done innumerable times.  But divide and conquer.  Find the row first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you don't seem to have provided HTML you want to act upon but just a screenshot and a link to some RoR code in the comments that generates the HTML.  Also you don't show how you try to execute `SveCrf.prototype.hideRowWhereNoTicksForm`, and furthermore I'm not really sure at all what you are trying to do with `switch/case` (I also don't understand what `item` is supposed to be; this is where providing us with actual HTML might have helped).

In addition, as I've alluded to in some comments of mine, you are really trying to do two things.  I don't know if you've seen this Stackoverflow page yet about [creating "a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but I think reviewing that will help improve your StackOverflow experience moving forward (and also for me it validated my suggestion of "divide and conquer").

All of which I think made it hard for you to get the help you desired.  In any case below I'm providing some sample HTML with a table containing four rows total, two with a cell that contains the class `foo`, and two that don't.  Beneath that is my non-jQuery code selecting the rows with no cells containing the class `foo`, and then hiding them; furthermore there is a demo of the same functionality using jQuery at https://repl.it/@dexygen/HideRowsWithNoCellsWithClass

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td class='foo'>foo</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>bar</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>baz</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="foo">foo</td><td>bar</td><td>baz</td></tr>
</table>

/*
We cannot call `filter` directly on an HTMLCollection such as returned by 
"document.getElementsByTagName('tr')" as it is not a bona fide array, so we use 
"[].filter.call()", and we return only those rows that *fail* the test 
"row.querySelector('td.foo')", then we loop over these with `forEach` and hide them
*/

[].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), function(row) {
    return !row.querySelector('td.foo');
}).forEach(function(row) {row.style.display = 'none'});
```